# why this mv command works

Tags: mv

I found this mv command but I can't find why it works:

```
sudo  mv /usr/share/dbus-1 /services/org.freedesktop.Notification.service{,.disabled}
```

I can't find this syntax in the man page.

Comment: Are you sure there should be a space between `/dbus-1` and `/services`? If not, then it is a simple [brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion)

Answer (score 4):

In that position in a command, the `{}` indicate a list of alternatives, which in this case are `""` and `".disabled"`. Try it yourself, with `echo` (and removing the space after `/dbus-1`:

```
$ echo /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notification.service{,.disabled}
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notification.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notification.service.disabled
```